# How to remove weekdays in duration data type NAV

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

How can i remove weekdays in the data type duration in CAL ?

for example:
duration := datetime2 - datetime1

But duration do contains Saturdays and Sundays. How can i remove them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: you can not.

But you can use the `Date` virtual table. Something like this:

```
Date.SETRANGE("Period Type", Date."Period Type"::Date);
Date.SETFILTER("Period Start", '%1..%2', DT2DATE(datetime1), DT2DATE(datetime2));
Date.SETRANGE("Period No.", 1, 5); // only days 1 - 5 = weekdays
EXIT(Date.COUNT); // returns number of days
```

You can then convert the number of days to a duration with a simple multiplication. A `Duration` is nothing more than the number of milliseconds.

1 hour = 3600000ms.

Therefore:

```
MESSAGE('%1', NoOfDays);
dur := NoOfDays * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
MESSAGE('%1', dur);
```

Comment: How can I convert integer (I will have the total of days as you proposed) to duration. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: @lam simple answer- you can’t

Comment: @Mak Sim you are wrong. You can. `Integer` and `Duration` are assignable to each other. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Hemisphera I know they are. Duration is basically an Integer. But it is not what was asked. @Lam wants to have duration between two points in time excluding weekends. So just multiplying days on milliseconds will not be an answer. You need something like `duration := datetime2 - datetime1 - DurationOfAllWeekends`

Comment: Yes it is the answer, **if** the number of days I am multiplying already are the days without weekends. And in my case they are, because I am using the `Date` table to find the number of days, not counting weekends. Of course you can count only entire days this way.